# Call a function of parent component from child

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component which has a modal dialog as child component, I have a function inside the parent component to close the dialog.

```
public _setShowTemplatePanel = (showTemplatePanel: boolean): (() => void) => {
    return (): void => {
        this.setState({ showTemplatePanel });
    };
}
```

in child component I have button to save the form and then I want to call the function from parent. the below code works well:

```
<PrimaryButton onClick={this.props.setShowTemplatePanel(false)}>Save </PrimaryButton>
```

But if want to call it from a function inside the child component it doesn't work, I need to perform some actions before call the parent function.

```
public _onClosePanel = () => {
    this.props.setShowTemplatePanel(false);
}
<DefaultButton onClick={()=>this._onClosePanel}>save</DefaultButton>
```

Comment: what is the exact problem, an error ?

Comment: Can you try `this._onClosePanel()` instead of `this._onClosePanel`

Comment: There seems to be no problem, when I click the button, onClosePanel fires but this line doesn't work: 
this.props.setShowTemplatePanel(false);  
I also tried this._onClosePanel(), but no luck!

Comment: Did you bind the method in the constructor? `this. _onClosePanel=this. _onClosePanel .bind(this);`

Comment: Which one is the parent and which one is the child? It is not really clear from your example.

Answer (score 0):

In JSX the code between brackets is executed, so `onClick={this.props.setShowTemplatePanel(false)}` will just call `this.props.setShowTemplatePanel(false)` on render. You need to, either assign it as an arrow function in its place or as a property of the class. In your last bit of code you actually did both, but only one is really necessary, like this:

```
public _onClosePanel = () => {
    this.props.setShowTemplatePanel(false);
}
<DefaultButton onClick={this._onClosePanel}>save</DefaultButton>
```

or this

```
<DefaultButton onClick={()=>this.props.setShowTemplatePanel(false)}>save</DefaultButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I used Office Fabric UI Panel and in the documentation they mention I have to add a method like this:

```
public _setShowPanel = (showPanel: boolean): (() => void) => {
    return (): void => {
        this.setState({ showPanel });
    };
}
```

So as you can see the type of the method is (()=>void) and I simply added () at the end of calling the method:

```
public _onClosePanel = () => {
    this.props.setShowTemplatePanel(false)();
}
```

That's it! it solved the problem!